# Vagrant up throws error

Tags: vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

Hello guys I'm trying to run the command vagrant up but it is throwing me an error. It was working day before yesterday and since yesterday it has been throwing me this error

```
The directory where plugins are installed (the Vagrant home directory)
has a space in it. On Windows, there is a bug in Ruby when compiling
plugins into directories with spaces. Please move your Vagrant home
directory to a path without spaces and try again.
```

Now I have googled it and what I got was there may be a space in the directory and yes those answers are right there is a space in some of the paths that are in the PATH variable  but the first question that I want to know that

> Why was it running it all the days before yestarday

and the second question is

> Which path do I have to correct since I personally never did it's installation the system I got had it configuration. Here are the paths that are in my path variable :

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\php;
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
D:\Ampps\mysql\bin;D:\Ampps\php;
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;
C:\Users\TBox Solutions\AppData\Local\atom\bin;
C:\Users\TBox Solutions\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;
C:\Users\TBox Solutions\AppData\Local\.meteor\;
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;
C:\Users\TBox Solutions\AppData\Local\Spoon\Cmd;
C:\Users\TBox Solutions\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: can somebody please tell me why was my question down voted ?

Comment: Maybe your question is related with configuration instead of programming issue?

Answer (score 0):

The message says:

```
The directory where plugins are installed (the Vagrant home directory)
has a space in it. On Windows, there is a bug in Ruby when compiling
plugins into directories with spaces. Please move your Vagrant home
directory to a path without spaces and try again.
```

You must to change your user name without spaces in it. for example TBox_Solutions.

Create a new user to test it.